# Accidental triggering of Recommend Deletion button on VLQ queue

Tags: bug, review, user-interface, low-quality-posts

Because of the speed of loading, it's very difficult to reproduce, but if you click somewhere near the bottom, in line with the <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd> button in the Low Quality section when it's loading, it appears to trigger it without any opportunity to look at the post.  If anyone else can reproduce this, that would be interesting.

**EDIT:** I've had this happen to me again - it seems that if you click <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd> more than once by accident that it triggers it also for the next post if it's an answer. However, I cannot confirm this 100%.

Comment: Observed independently: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222474/race-condition-in-low-quality-audit

Comment: [You're not alone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244500/152859).