# Race condition in Low Quality audit

Tags: bug, user-interface, review-audits, low-quality-posts, javascript

I was just reviewing in the Low Quality queue, and after clicking the confirmation button on the dialog to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4128641) as "question as an answer", I accidentally clicked again somewhere in the vicinity of that button; I'm not sure whether I double-clicked it or clicked in the blank region after it was removed from the DOM.

In either case, this clicking on something that was very much *not* the "Recommend Deletion" button registered as a recommend-deletion action anyway, leading to what turned out to be [this failed audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4128685). This appears to be a race condition in the JavaScript code for the review wizard, possibly one that double-submits the "recommend deletion as another question posted as an answer" either without properly tagging with the question ID or that updates the question-ID variable before disabling the button on the popup dialog as "already submitted".

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Regardless of whether that happened or is a fish tale, I was amused to see that your rep is exactly 1337.

Comment: Yes, I've definitely had this happen to me, multiple times. For example, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210542/recommend-deletion-on-a-question) is an example of that. I put [another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203086/accidental-triggering-of-recommend-deletion-button-on-vlq-queue) before, but no one had responded to it.

Comment: _Is there some significance to 1337?_ Yes. [Yes there is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet)